# In few words, what can be said about Func<>

Tags: c#, func

I've been seing **Func<>** for sometime now, and I've manage to avoid it (for now). But, now it looks like I can't dodge it forever. For instance, I tried Dynamic Linq, but almost everything was in terms of Func<>. I've tried one of my book (C# 2008/Deitel&Deitel) and also MSDN but I'm not getting it yet. They all jump straight in the subject.

1. What can be said (in few words) about Func<>
2. Can I get some links on the web that can get me started on that matter?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Jon Skeet's book on c sharp has an excellent few chapters on this and why it is so important to lambda functions and linq.

Comment: There is nothing scary about, and no reason to avoid, Func or generic delegates - they are simply delegates that represent general methods that take a certain number of arguments.

Comment: You may want to look at the various Func questions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/func

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's so great about Func<> delegate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319789/whats-so-great-about-func-delegate)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`Func<>` is a generic delegate - it is just very convenient to use, because you don't have to create your own delegate for each argument/return type combination.
Earlier, you had to write something like:

```
public delegate long MyDelegate( int number );

public void Method( IEnumerable<int> list, MyDelegate myDelegate )
{
    foreach( var number in list )
    {
        myDelegate( number );
    }
}
```

You had to publish your delegate so that a user can call your method correctly. Especially when you need a bunch of different delegates you ended up publishing one for every argument list and return type.
With `Func<>` you just write:

```
public void Method( IEnumerable<int> list, Func<int, long> myDelegate )
{
    foreach( var number in list )
    {
        myDelegate( number );
    }
}
```

It means the same as the first code example - `Func<int, long>` defines a delegate that takes one integer argument and returns a long value.

Of course you can use longer parameter lists, too: `Func<int, int, bool, long>` will still return a *long* value while it takes two *ints* and a *bool* value. If you wish a delegate without return value you will have to use `Action<>`, which will have *void* as a return type.

**EDIT** (by request): *How to call the method in my example*:

For the caller, there is no difference between the solution with `MyDelegate` or `Func<>`. In both cases he has three options to call the method:

Using a lambda notation (C# 3.0 required, probably the best solution for short methods):

```
Method( myList, i => i * i );
```

By using an anonymous method (C# 2.0 required):

```
Method( myList, delegate( int i )
{
    return i * i;
} );
```

Or by using a real method as an argument:

```
Method( myList, Square );

private static long Square( int number )
{
    return number * number;
}
```

Comment: Good explanation. Would be good to include an example of using/calling the Method as well.

Comment: @Metro: I added some examples how to call the method

Comment: Related great answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319789/whats-so-great-about-func-delegate

Answer (score 12):

`Func<...>` is a *family* of delegate types, that return some value, and take some number of arguments; for example:

- `Func<int,bool>` is simply something that takes an int and returns a bool (the return is always at the end); for example a predicate:

  ```
  int[] data = {1,2,3,4,5};
  var odd = data.Where(i => i % 2 == 0);
  ```
- `Func<string>` is a method that returns string, such as `() => "hello world";`.
- `Func<DateDtime, TimeSpan, DateTime>` might be something like `(when,howLong) => when + howLong;`

Likewise there is `Action<...>` which does the same but without a return type.

There's nothing magic about `Func<...>` - it is just a simpler way of expressing delegates, while a: using generics (useful for LINQ), or b: not needing you to look up what the arguments are; if the delegate type is something obscure (`PipeStreamImpersonationWorker` for example) it can be hard to know what it takes; if that was expressed as the comparable `Action` it would be clear that it takes no parameters and returns `void`.

Answer (score 10):

This might help. Suppose every time you see `Func<int, string>` you think to yourself:

```
interface IFuncIntString
{
    string Invoke(int x);
}
```

That is, the delegate is an object that implements this interface. It has a single method called Invoke which takes an int and returns a string.

Now add to that the feature that you can omit the "Invoke" on a call, and you've got yourself a delegate.

Comment: That's how I like to think of delegates.

Comment: Best way to explain it to a Java programmer ;)

Answer (score 7):

`Func<int>` (for example) is a type (in the way that `string` is a type). So you use it to declare variables, fields, parameters and so on.

It represents a computation that can be done whenever you ask it for an answer:

```
Func<int> f = () => DateTime.Now.Second;

// elsewhere...

Console.WriteLine( f() );
```

Note how you can call it just like a method. There are many overloaded versions of `Func` to support different numbers of parameters. The last type argument is the return type.

```
Func<int, string> quoteInt = n => "\"" + n + "\"";

Console.WriteLine( quoteInt(3) );
```

`Func` is a delegate type. You can declare your own, but it's easier to use `Func`. Where you want to return `void`, use `Action` instead of `Func`. You only need to declare custom delegates if you need `out` or `ref` parameters.

When assigning a lambda to a `Func`, you can refer to local variables. This is extremely powerful; it means that a `Func` is more than just code; it has data. So it's like an object with a single method (which technically it is - the method is called `Invoke` and the compiler implicitly calls that method for you when you call a delegate).

The syntax `() =>` can be placed before any expression to say "don't do this now, delay it until later". It allows you to initialize a delegate capturing the delayed computation. And then the syntax `()` can be placed after the delegate to actually trigger the computation. So suffix `()` is kind-of the opposite of prefix `() =>`.

Answer (score 3):

You can start with [101 Linq Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx).

In short, `Func<>` is a delegate where the last type parameter is the return type.

So, `Func<int,bool>` is a delegate that takes an `int` parameter and returns a `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

Func<..., T> is delegate. 
where T is return-type, and all others - input parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If you've ever used the => operator in c#, and you probably have, you've already used Funcs.  You just haven't been explicitly declaring them.

So, if you write a statement like

```
var peopleWhoLikeBlue = people.Where(person => person.FavoriteColor == "Blue");
```

you're passing a `Func<Person, bool>` into the Where() method.

If you want to be wordy, you can rewrite that statement like this:

```
Func<Person, bool> favoriteColorIsBlue = person => person.FavoriteColor == "Blue";
var peopleWhoLikeBlue = people.Where(favoriteColorIsBlue);
```

And you'll get the same result.