# () => construct

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, c#-3.0, oauth, c#-2.0

I am in the process of converting a project from visual studio 2005 to visual studio 2008 and came up on the above construct.

```
using Castle.Core.Resource;
using Castle.Windsor;
using Castle.Windsor.Configuration.Interpreters;
using CommonServiceLocator.WindsorAdapter;
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;

namespace MyClass.Business
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public override void Init()
        {
            IServiceLocator injector =
                new WindsorServiceLocator(
                    new WindsorContainer(
                        new XmlInterpreter(
                            new ConfigResource("oauth.net.components"))));

            //ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => injector);

            // ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(injector);
        }
    }
}
```

ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => injector);

Can I get an understanding of what this is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

I guess that the `SetLocatorProvider` method has a signature like:

```
SetLocatorProvider( Func<IServiceLocator> callback ):
```

Now you have to provide such a callback. There are basically three options:

*Use a **method** (always working):*

```
private IServiceLocator GetServiceLocator() { /* return IServiceLocator */ }

ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider( GetServiceLocator() );
```

*Use a **delegate** (requires C#2.0):*

```
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider( delegate
        {
            // return IServiceLocator
        } );
```

*Use a **lambda** (requires C#3.0):*
That's the code you see ...
Since there is no argument (`Func<IServiceLocator>` has only a return value) you specify this by using `()`:

```
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider( () => { /* return IServiceLocator */ } );
```

this can be translated to

```
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider( () => /* IServiceLocator */ );
```

Maybe you want to read [this question + answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661669/in-few-words-what-can-be-said-about-func/2661718#2661718), too.

Answer (score 2):

It's the lambda notation to create an inline delegate without parameter.

Answer (score 2):

It's a lambda. If you're familiar with delegates, it's like declaring a method which returns `injector` and using that as a delegate, except you've inlined the method.

The first `()` contains the arguments to the lambda. For instance, in event handling, you'll often see `(src, e)` where `src` is the originator of the event and `e` is the event itself. The arguments are then available for the subsequent code to use.

If it's multiline, you can put `(args) => { brackets }` around the delegate and return the value. This is shorthand.

Comment: How do I convert it back to Visual Studio construct

Comment: It should work fine in VS2008. If you want it in old-style, turn the lambda into a method and use that as a delegate instead:  

    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(CreateInjector);

Comment: @ferronrsmith - The actual .Net types for lambdas are the generic `Func<>` and `Action<>` types. The generic arguments represent the function arguments (and return type for Func<>). These are just special delegate classes which make things easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

It is a lambda expression that creates an anonymous delegate.  That is, its a function declared inline.  The parameter list is inside the paranthesis, so in this case there are no parameters.  And when the function contains a single statement it implicitly returns the value of that statement (or returns nothing at all).

In this specific case, it is a function that returns the injector.  This is a common pattern for a ServiceLocator, to initialize it with a function that returns the IoC container.

Comment: An anonymous delegate would look more like `new delegate() { return injector; }`.  Granted, the lamdba expression has the effect of creating an anonymous delegate in this case.

Comment: you're right, and I was in a hurry.  I edited my answer to clarify the point better..

Answer (score 0):

It is not a constructor but a Lambda expression.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) for more detail.

In this case () means no parameters => is the Lamda operator and injector is being returned.